# How to change page title in CakePHP 2.5?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

From [2.5 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-5-migration-guide.html#id1):

> `$title_for_layout` is deprecated. Use `$this->fetch('title');` and
>   `$this->assign('title', 'your-page-title');` instead.

They work in Views, but what to do in Controller? Using `$this->assign()` throws Fatal error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set this in your controller's function()

```
$title = 'Title of your page | Site';
$this->set(compact('title'));
```

then you can use $title in your views to change the title of your page. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'List User');
```

inside controller.

Comment: yes. $this->set('title_for_layout', 'List User'); will work in 2.5.5 also.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia , yes it works thanks , m using same cakephp version and it works .

Answer (score 5):

You have to use

```
$this->assign('title',$title);
```

in view files.

In layout, You can also use

```
$this->fetch('title', $title);
```

to set the title

You can use `$this->set('title_for_layout',$title);` but you should not as it will be removed very soon

Comment: thanks, I know what to do in View files (including layouts), question was about Controllers, which r3mmel posted the answer.

Comment: whatever works for you is great, but i am still confused over how $this->assign('title', 'your-page-title'); can throw fatal error in view, i thought you added that on your controller

Comment: Yes I used it in Controller, not in View. (re-read first post again, plz)